# Django Effecient way to Perform Query on M2M

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

```
class A(models.Model)
  results = models.TextField()
```

```
class B(models.Model)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  res = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

- Let's suppose we have above 2 models. `A` model has millions of objects.

I would like to know what would be the best efficient/fastest way to get all the `results objects` of a particular `B` object.

- Let's suppose we have to retrieve all results for object number `5` of `B`

```
Option 1 :  A.objects.filter(b__id=5)

   (OR)

Option 2 : B.objects.get(id=5).res.all()
```

- Option 1: My Question is filtering by id on  `A` model objects would take lot of time?  since there are millions of `A` model objects.
- Option 2: Question: does `res` field on `B` model stores the `id` value of `A` model objects?

The reason why I'm assuming the option `2` would be a faster way since it stores the reference of `A` model objects & directly getting those object values first and making the second query to fetch the results.  whereas in the first option filtering by id or any other field would take up a lot of time

Comment: The first one will only make one query, whereas the latter makes two queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **first expression** will result in **one** database query. Indeed, it will query with:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
INNER JOIN a_b ON a_b.a_id = a.id
WHERE a_b.b_id = 5
```

The **second expression** will result in **two** queries. Indeed, first Django will query to fetch that specific `B` object with a query like:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM b
WHERE b.id = 5
```

then it will make exactly the same query to retrieve the related `A` objects.

But retrieving the `A` object is here not necessary (unless you of course need it somewhere else). You thus make a useless database query.

> My Question is filtering by id on A model objects would take lot of time? since there are millions of A model objects.

A database normally stores an index on foreign key fields. This thus means that it will filter effectively. The total number of `A` objects is usually not (that) relevant (since it uses a datastructure to accelerate search like a [*B-tree* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)). The wiki page has a section [named *An index speeds the search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#An_index_speeds_the_search) that explains how this works.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant explanation, I would like to know by default database would store index on all fields or just `id` or `pk` ?

Comment: @ArbazzHussain: normally a primary key indeed has an index. You can add extra indexes on other fields, by setting the `db_index=True`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index